# FB.api('/me/friends') throws error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

I'm not sure its something I did wrong, (everything seems to go wrong in ie with the facebook sdk)

When I get the facebook friends FB.api('/me/friends' (already logged in), I got a weird error, "enable to get the property list"

On ie8 & ie9, it works on chrome and FF, anyone got a workaround?

Comment: 1. Show us the code. 2. Provide exact error message (don't paraphrase it)

Answer (score 1):

**I assume you use JavaScript and FBML because you tagged JavaScript and FBML**

Here are the reasons of getting error in ***ie***

Verify that you did place the below code correctly as I think you didn't.

**1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.**

The following code will load and initialize the JavaScript SDK with all common options. Replace YOUR_APP_ID and WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM with the appropriate values. The best place to put this code is right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

**2. Add an XML namespace to the `<html>` tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.**

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Thanks